# Flash alert Error not displaying Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash-message

So I have two flash notice that should appear one if a post is saved successfully and another if there is an error creating a new post . I implemented it a while back but I just realized that the error flash isn't being displayed properly. All it displays is a red empty notice on top of the window, while the notice for a "successful save" does appear correctly.

for my controller i have :

```
  def create
     @topic = Topic.new
     @topic.name = params[:topic][:name]
     @topic.description = params[:topic][:description]
     @topic.public = params[:topic][:public]

     if @topic.save
       redirect_to @topic, notice: "Topic was saved successfully."
     else
       flash.now[:alert] = "Error creating topic. Please try again."
       render :new
     end
   end
```

new post view :

```
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post } %>

  </div>
</div>
```

_form.html:

```
<%= form_for [topic, post] do |f| %>
  <% if post.errors.any? %>
  <div class="alert alert-denger">
    <h4><%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %>.</h4>
    <ul>
      <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= form_group_tag(post.errors[:title]) do %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post title" %>
  <% end %>
<%= form_group_tag(post.errors[:body]) do %>
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post body" %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: provide please your view, how you implement error message?

Comment: Try putting the `flash.now[:alert] = "Error creating topic. Please try again."` after `render :new`

Comment: @OlegSobchuk i have provided the New Post View. and i tried it still getting a blank red notification with no words in it

Comment: I still can't found where you implemented `flash messages` in your view? I can see just errors, but not `flash messages`

Answer (score 0):

Please put this in application.html.erb file.

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `flash` massages in your `application.html.erb`:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
     <%= value %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

usually it put above `<%= yield %>`